# Haskell negating functions

Tags: haskell

This is my task: 
Write a function:

```
onlyDigits :: String -> String
```

that strips all non-digit characters from a string (for example, onlyDigits "ac245d62"
is "24562").

I have this:

```
onlyDigits :: String -> String
onlyDigits a = [ (not)isAlpha b | b <- a ]
```

But i can't compile it

Can anyone see where i've gone wrong?

Comment: Look here: https://www.fpcomplete.com/school/starting-with-haskell/basics-of-haskell/function-application

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By writing

```
(not) isAlpha b
```

you're applying `not` to the two arguments `isAlpha` and `b`, and that's probably why the compiler complains.

If you fix this little mistake and now write:

```
onlyDigits :: String -> String
onlyDigits a = [ not (isAlpha b) | b <- a ]
```

you'll still get an error since this creates a list of `Bool`s!

---

What you probably want is:

```
onlyDigits :: String -> String
onlyDigits a = [ b | b <- a, not $ isAlpha b ]
```

This will take all the elements `b` of `a`, that fulfil the condition `not (isAlpha b)`.

You could also use the `filter` function and have a point-free function:

```
onlyDigits :: String -> String
onlyDigits = filter (not.isAlpha)
```

or even better:

```
onlyDigits :: String -> String
onlyDigits = filter isDigit
```

to only keep digits!

Answer (score 1):

You actually have 2 errors.

The first one is a type error, stemming from not using function application correctly.

But the second one is that your function will still not do what you want if you only filter one category of unwanted characters. For example, you also do not want space characters. Or graphic symbols.

Sometimes, it is better to say "I want this" instead of "I want anything but ... (long list)".
So, filter for the property you want, not for the negation of one of the  properties you don't want.